# MYSQL - JOIN to the last record on right table PREVIOUS to record from left table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I've seen many questions similar to this one, but not quite like this.
What i need to do is to LEFT JOIN records, to the immediately previous record on the right table.  for example:

```
LEFT TABLE 'PROD':
idMachine |production | prod.date
1         |10         | 2016-05-02
2         |11         | 2016-05-15
3         |14         | 2016-06-01
3         |13         | 2016-06-15

RIGHT TABLE 'CONFIG':
idMachine | sett   | config.date
1         |  30    | 2016-04-01
2         |  25    | 2016-04-01
3         |  20    | 2016-04-01
1         |  40    | 2016-05-01
3         |  45    | 2016-06-10
1         |  50    | 2016-06-15

and the result should be:
idMachine |production | sett   | prod.date
1         |10         | 40     | 2016-05-02
2         |11         | 25     | 2016-05-15
3         |14         | 20     | 2016-06-01
3         |13         | 45     | 2016-06-15
```

the system works like this, i record all production runs on machines, and i record every change on the config of each machine, what i need to know, is what settings it had for that production run.
If you notice, in the result, for machines 1 and 3, the join is not done to the LATEST record of the config, but to the LAST record before the production happened, in that way we could know what we produced with what settings.

I've tried joins with `JOIN CONFIGS ON prod.date > config.date`  but it joins to EVERY config previous, not only the last. and if I use LIMIT it doesnt give me all the records i need.
I've tried some JOINS to subqueries using MAX, but the subquery returns only the latest config, and not the previous configs, so "old" runs dont have configs...

Any help is very appreciated!!!

Comment: There are primary keys.. I just didn't include them in this example, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery also needs to be a JOIN of the two tables to allow you to get the preceding date in CONFIG for each PROD. Then include that subquery in a join with the tables again to find the `sett` value.

Something like this:

```
SELECT p2.idMachine, p2.production, c2.sett, p2.date
FROM PROD AS p2
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT p.idMachine, p.`date` AS prodDate, MAX(c.`date`) AS prev
    FROM PROD AS p 
    INNER JOIN CONFIG AS c 
       ON p.idMachine = c.idMachine AND p.`date` >= c.`date`
    GROUP BY p.idMachine, prodDate
) AS prevs
   ON p2.idMachine = prevs.idMachine AND p2.`date` = prevs.prodDate
INNER JOIN CONFIG AS c2
   ON prevs.idMachine = c2.idMachine AND prevs.prev = c2.`date`
```

If you have a `WHERE` clause to filter the PROD records you care about, you'll probably want to put it in both the subquery and main query... wait a sec...

---

Depending on how your data is "shaped" this version with one less join *may* be better.

```
SELECT p2.idMachine, p2.production, c2.sett, p2.date
FROM (SELECT p.idMachine, p.production, p.`date`, MAX(c.`date`) AS prevConfigDate
    FROM PROD AS p 
    INNER JOIN CONFIG AS c 
       ON p.idMachine = c.idMachine AND p.`date` >= c.`date`
    GROUP BY p.idMachine, p.production, p.`date`
) AS p2
INNER JOIN CONFIG AS c2
   ON p2.idMachine = c2.idMachine AND p2.prevConfigDate = c2.`date`
```

However, the subquery here calculates the MAX for every PROD, instead of just every (idMachine, date); so it may cost more than the extra join did. In this case though, the redundant `WHERE` clauses are not needed (just one copy in the subquery).

---

And on I go... there is also a correlated subquery version, though I am not fond of them...

```
SELECT p.*
    , (SELECT sett 
       FROM CONFIG AS c 
       WHERE c.idMachine = p.idMachine 
          AND c.date <= p.date 
       ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 1
      ) AS sett
FROM PROD AS p
;
```

**Also note that in all these I compared the dates with `>=` or `<=`, not `<` or `>`; you may need to adjust according to your actual data/logic.**

Comment: Thanks!!! honestly i haven't tried the first 2 options (because, as i said in other comment PROD was already a comples query simplified in this example), but the third one did the trick, i just had to add DESC  in the ORDER BY of the subquery, because it was getting the first config before the record, and not the last... but it works now!! (i'll edit the answer)   i know it's not the best option, and even less if i have to do a subquery for each column (in my case I need 2), but for now i will do it like this, optimization comes later!!! =)  thanks a lot for all the options you gave me!!!

Comment: @aampudia Oh, oops, forgot the `desc` on `order by`; I'll edit for future references. My main issue with correlated subqueries like that is you are practically running another query separately for each and every row in the outer query's results. (1000 results from PROD = 1000 queries to CONFIG).

Answer (score 0):

tested with your data and working

```
SELECT *
FROM PROD
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM `CONFIG`
GROUP BY idMachine
ORDER BY `config.date` ASC
) AS CONFIG ON PROD.idMachine = CONFIG.idMachine
WHERE `config.date` <= PROD.`prod.date`
```

> idMachine    production  prod.date   idMachine   sett    config.date
>
> 1     10  2016-05-02  1   40  2016-05-01
>
> 2     11  2016-05-15  2   25  2016-04-01
>
> 3     14  2016-06-01  3   20  2016-04-01
>
> 3     13  2016-06-15  3   20  2016-04-01

Comment: Thanks, tony! There are primary keys, i just didnt include them in the example, as i thought it wouldnt be needed for the join...

Comment: did the sql above work?  was it what you needed?  edited the primary key comment.

Comment: Hi!! Thanks for the answer!!   this answer has the same problem i had before! Because if you see your output for the machine 3, theyre both the same,  because youre filtering the first appearance of each machine's config and then from those records you match each machine id.... i dont know if im being clear enough.

Comment: @tonygil that subquery is just going to give a near-random row from config for each machine id.

Comment: I havent yet, i was in the field and had no internet,  and also it seems a lot more difficult since my PROD table is already a complex query with subqueries and such...  i used PROD here for simplicity, so it will take a little longer to test...